# jQuery Ajax Script (Determining Week Begin- & Startdate using PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got the following php Script saved as **getweek.php**:

```
if(isset($_GET["week"]) && isset($_GET["year"])){

    function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
        $dto = new DateTime();
        $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
        $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
        $dto->modify('+6 days');
        $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
        return $ret;
    }

    $week_array = getStartAndEndDate($_GET["week"], $_GET["year"]);
    if(isset($_GET["start"])){
        echo $week_array['week_start'];
    } else if(isset($_GET["end"])){
        echo $week_array['week_end'];
    }
}
```

This script is called by my jQuery AJAX Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkDate").click(function(){
            var week = $("#mdj_week").val();
            var year = $("#mdj_year").val();

            $("#week_start").load("getweek.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year + "&start");
            $("#week_end").load("getweek.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year + "&end");
        })
    });
```

The ID's mdj_week & mdj_year are both input fields. mdj_week asks for a week number (eg Week 52) and mdj_year aks for a year.

The PHP Script should return the first and the last day of the given week. if I call the PHP-script directly it is workign without a problem, however .load seems to give me the current date (the output is 2015-11-21 & 2015-11-27)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the post data sent to php from .load? Ie. is the week and year value correct?

Comment: @Tristan Turned out, I used the wrong ID for one of my input-fields containing the values sent to the PHP script. This seemed to leed to this error. The Question is now resolved, thank you!